# How to validate/limit attachment file size

Tags: phoenix-framework, ecto, arc-ecto

In an Ecto model with attachment using `arc` and `arc_ecto`:

```
  use Arc.Ecto.Schema

  schema "profiles" do
    ...
    field :avatar, MyApp.AvatarUploader.Type
    ...

    timestamps()
  end
```

How can I validate/limit the size of the attachment? 
I read about it in the [guides](http://www.phoenixframework.org/docs/file-uploads#section-configuring-upload-limits) with the configuration of `Plug.Parsers` but I would like to do this at a model level and not at the application level. For instance the user avatar should be small but other picture should be larger.

What's the best way to achieve this?

Comment: are you trying to restrict this on pixel size or file size?

Comment: As I'm using arc I can resize the dimension of the image. But my goal is to limit the max size of a file that the end user can attempt to upload. So I'm trying to limit the file size.

Comment: the best solution I can come up with is to add some javascript that checks the files size `myInp.files[0].size` and prevents upload that way. You can do this server side as well with a combination of `{:ok, %{size: size}} = File.stat("uploaded_file")` and a custom validation, but from memory this will require the file to be first uploaded to the server and then rejected. So if that's ok, let me know and I'll write up an example

Comment: I totally agreed with you, javascript can be used on the client side to make the validation before it reaches the server. But in the case of no js or api or for the curiosity your exemple is welcome! Another thing that I haven't figured out yet is how/where Phoenix does this with `Plug.Parsers`

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone is wondering, I believe can validate before storing the file in the module where you define your arc definitions: https://github.com/stavro/arc#file-validation

Something like the following:

```
def validate({%Arc.File{path: path}, _}) do
  %{size: size} = File.stat!(path)
  # less than 100 bytes
  size < 100
end
```

This should work with arc_ecto